# How does operator chaining happen in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a totally basic C++ question here.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 255;
    cout << hex << a << endl; // <-----
}
```

**In the code piece above, how is the `std::cout` statement chained?**

I understand that an implementation of `cout` would return the reference to `cout` object to allow chaining to happen, so it should be executed as:

```
(((cout << hex) << a) << endl)
```

i.e. equivalent to these, in order

1. `cout << hex`
2. `cout << a`
3. `cout << endl`

But this cannot be the case because somehow value of `a` needs to be converted to `hex` form!

**How are operators actually chained by the compiler to make the conversion happen?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how `hex` is usually implemented:

```
inline ios_base&
hex(ios_base& __base)
{
    __base.setf(ios_base::hex, ios_base::basefield);
    return __base;
}
```

As you can see, `hex` does not perform any conversion by itself: instead, it sets an option in the base stream to use hex for printing of numbers passed into it at a later point.

**EDIT** (in response to a comment)

As hammar correctly notes, the other part of the puzzle is how `hex(ios_base& __base)` is being called. There is an overload of the `<<` operator with this signature:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& (*)(ostream&))
```

This overload is essential implementation detail of  [*stream manipulators*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/). It is this overload that calls `hex`, and lets it do its "magic" (which of course should not sound like magic to you any longer).

Comment: You should probably also mention the other part of the puzzle, the `ostream& operator <<(ostream& (*)(ostream&))` overload, which is how manipulators like `hex` actually get called.

Comment: @hammar Great observation! Thank you very much for the comment, I edited the answer to reflect this essential point.

Answer (score 22):

You've got it right, that's exactly how it works. `hex` just has a special type that changes the internal state of the `cout` object when passed to its `operator<<` function. The internal state then determines how any future values passed to `cout` via `operator<<` are treated.

`std::hex` happens to be a function. `cout << hex` doesn't call the hex function as such, however: it passes a pointer to the hex function to an `operator<<` overload for `ostream` which accepts function pointers with a particular signature. `hex()` is then called from inside the operator implementation via that function pointer, and modifies the `ostream` object from there as far as I know.

Comment: `hex` is not a *special type*. It is a function. (or simply saying, `hex` *has* a special type, doesn't make sense. What does *has* mean here?)

Comment: Yes, it happens to have function type. It's the type that determines which `operator<<` overload gets called, though. `cout << hex` doesn't call the `hex` function as such: it passes a pointer to the hex function to an `operator<<` overload which accepts function pointers with a particular signature. `hex()` is then called from inside the operator implementation, as far as I know.

Comment: @Nawaz: `hex` "has" the type of a particular function signature in the same way `a` "has" type `int` in the code fragment `int a = 1;`

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is: for the user of `cout` it's completely irrelevant that `hex` is a function. You can treat it as a special value that changes the internal state of `cout`.

Comment: I haven't seen *has* being used that way. I usually say : `hex` is of special type, or `a` is of type `int` rather than `a` has type `int`.

Comment: I think the hairs have been sufficiently split at this point. Feel free to suggest any edits to the answer if you feel it could be improved. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: FWIW, I use "has" with "type" in the same way that pmjordan does. This is a very common phrasing; [`"has type t"` gets hundreds of thousands of hits on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q="has+type+t"). (Not as many, admittedly, as [`"is of type t"`](https://www.google.com/search?q="is+of+type+t").)

Answer (score 2):

`std::hex` actually sets a flag inside the `std::cout` object, which will stick until reset IIRC. The `operator<<` themselves are evaluated left-to-right, so your parens are correct.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view hex is just a package object which has a side-effect on the cout object. After this cout will only output hexadecimal values.

Answer (score 1):

std::hex is a function which changes the state of a std::ostream object. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/hex/