# Return Type of Overloading >>

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

Is there any good reason why the standard way of overloading the >> operator for any class returns an object of type istream (or any input stream).

For example, due to this, code like

```
y = (cin >> x) ;
```

won't work and it would have if overloading `>>` had a return type of the input object.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, due to this, code like
>
> `(cin >> x) = y;`
>
> won't work. And it would have if overloading >> had a return type of
>   the input object.

No, it wouldn't necessarily - you would in many cases see `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`, unless you return a reference. ([click here for a demonstration](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2P2HgI%245))

The general reason is that it allows *chaining*, e.g. doing things like

```
mystream >> a >> b >> c;
```

For input/output streams, there is also the added benefit that the stream can be converted to `void*` (C++03) or `bool` (C++11), which allows checking for errors in constructs such as

```
while (cin >> x) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because then something like 
    cin >> x >> y 
would not work. And this is used far more often than the previous example.

Answer (score 0):

In very few situations would `(cin >> x) = y;` ever be desired. It's *expected* that the left-hand variable is the one being returned. Example: `(x += 5) = 7`, 'x' is returned and then set to 7 - '5' isn't what's returned. So the expected result of `(cin >> x)` is for 'cin' to be returned, which allows the implementation of [operator chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555555/how-does-operator-chaining-happen-in-c).

In your: '(cin >> x) = y;', the expected way to read it is "cin >> x", and then "cin = 7". Which doesn't make much sense. Returning something else, just confuses the programmer reading your code, because their expectations aren't met. (See [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment))

That doesn't mean 'x  y' *always* needs to return a reference to the left hand side. Frequently, it might make more sense for it to return something else. For example, 'myInt >> 4' returns *a copy* of 'myInt' bit-shifted 4 places to the right.

Comment: thanks, I changed my example to (cin >> x) = y